# Import "statsmodels.tsa.stattools.pacf" could not be resolved (Pylance report MissingImports)

Tags: python, import, statsmodels, pylance

I successfully installed statsmodels and its dependencies, but when trying to import statsmodels.tsa.stattools.pacf in VSCode, I get the yellow line warning saying :
"Import "statsmodels.tsa.stattools.pacf" could not be resolved (Pylance report MissingImports)"

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if the python environment you installed `statsmodels` in, is the same environment VSCode is using? Make sure that VSCode is using the same environment by selecting `Python: Select Interpreter` in the VSCode command palette.